# Shift and add binary multiplier getting don't-cares for reg2

Tags: verilog, digital, vlsi

```
module bin_mult(
    output reg [7:0]mult,reg1,reg2,
    output reg [2:0]count,
    input [3:0]a,b,
    input load,clk);

    //reg [7:0]reg1,reg2;
    //reg [2:0]count;
    reg [3:0]m[3:0];
    integer i,j;
    
    // Partial product generation
    always@(*) begin
        for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1) begin
            for(j=0;j<4;j=j+1) begin
                m[i][j]=b[i]&a[j];
            end
        end
    end

    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if(load) begin
            reg1<=0;
            count<=0;
            reg2<={4'd0,m[0]};
        end
        else if(count==4'd3) count<=0;
        else begin
                count<=count+1;
                if(b[count+1]==1'b1) begin
                    reg1<={4'd0,m[count+1]}<<(count+1);
                    mult<=reg1+reg2;
                    reg2<=mult;
                end
                else if(b[count+1]==1'b0) reg2<=reg2;
        end
    end
endmodule

module tb;
wire [7:0]mult,reg1,reg2;
wire [2:0]count;
reg [3:0]a,b;
reg load,clk;
bin_mult DUT(mult,reg1,reg2,count,a,b,load,clk);
always #5 clk=~clk;
initial begin
    $dumpfile("tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,tb);
    $monitor("clk=%b load=%b a=%d b=%d count=%d reg1=%b reg2=%b mult=%d",clk,load,a,b,count,reg1,reg2,mult);
    {clk,load}=0;
    @(negedge clk) a=4'd15;b=4'd15;
    @(negedge clk) load=1'b1;
    @(negedge clk) load=1'b0;
    #100 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

This was the simulation result:

```
VCD info: dumpfile tb.vcd opened for output.
clk=0 load=0 a= x b= x count=x reg1=xxxxxxxx reg2=xxxxxxxx mult=  x
clk=1 load=0 a= x b= x count=x reg1=xxxxxxxx reg2=xxxxxxxx mult=  x
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=x reg1=xxxxxxxx reg2=xxxxxxxx mult=  x
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=x reg1=xxxxxxxx reg2=xxxxxxxx mult=  x
clk=0 load=1 a=15 b=15 count=x reg1=xxxxxxxx reg2=xxxxxxxx mult=  x
clk=1 load=1 a=15 b=15 count=0 reg1=00000000 reg2=00001111 mult=  x
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=0 reg1=00000000 reg2=00001111 mult=  x
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=1 reg1=00011110 reg2=xxxxxxxx mult= 15
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=1 reg1=00011110 reg2=xxxxxxxx mult= 15
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=2 reg1=00111100 reg2=00001111 mult=  x
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=2 reg1=00111100 reg2=00001111 mult=  x
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=3 reg1=01111000 reg2=xxxxxxxx mult= 75
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=3 reg1=01111000 reg2=xxxxxxxx mult= 75
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=0 reg1=01111000 reg2=xxxxxxxx mult= 75
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=0 reg1=01111000 reg2=xxxxxxxx mult= 75
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=1 reg1=00011110 reg2=01001011 mult=  x
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=1 reg1=00011110 reg2=01001011 mult=  x
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=2 reg1=00111100 reg2=xxxxxxxx mult=105
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=2 reg1=00111100 reg2=xxxxxxxx mult=105
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=3 reg1=01111000 reg2=01101001 mult=  x
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=3 reg1=01111000 reg2=01101001 mult=  x
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=0 reg1=01111000 reg2=01101001 mult=  x
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=0 reg1=01111000 reg2=01101001 mult=  x
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=1 reg1=00011110 reg2=xxxxxxxx mult=225
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=1 reg1=00011110 reg2=xxxxxxxx mult=225
clk=1 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=2 reg1=00111100 reg2=11100001 mult=  x
test.v:56: $finish called at 130 (1s)
clk=0 load=0 a=15 b=15 count=2 reg1=00111100 reg2=11100001 mult=  x
```

I have taken two registers `reg1` to store partial product terms and `reg2` to store intermediate result (initialized it with first partial product terms array `m[0]`), but I'm getting unknown state for `reg2`.

When `count` becomes 1, the `reg2` has to hold its previous value, i.e., 00001111, but instead it is getting x. After that at many places `reg2` is getting x. I'm unable to find the reason.

Comment: Can you upload the waveform if possible?

Answer (score 2):

`reg2` is unknown because `mult` is unknown.

One way to resolve the unknowns is to set `mult` to 0 when `load` is 1, just like your other signals:

```
always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(load) begin
        reg1<=0;
        count<=0;
        reg2<={4'd0,m[0]};
        mult <= 0;
    end
```